# Python quit unexpectedly, Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pulp

I have installed python 2.7.12. I used "pip install pulp" to install pulp package. My problem is that "import pulp" gives me the following error. How can I solve this problem. Let me know if you need something else to debug. I have a Mackbook pro with El Capitan 10.11.5 os.

```
import pulp
Segmentation fault: 11


Process: Python [1707]
Path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Identifier: Python
Version: 2.7.12 (2.7.12)
Code Type: X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process: bash [1695]
Responsible: Terminal [1693]
User ID: 501

Date/Time: 2016-06-28 12:43:05.355 -0700
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version: 11
Anonymous UUID: BAE25C51-36E8-EE34-FFC5-11B186F972FB

Sleep/Wake UUID: 18A10F82-634B-4BE9-9373-AE13BA40FC4C

Time Awake Since Boot: 32000 seconds
Time Since Wake: 2900 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000008

VM Regions Near 0x8:
--> 
__TEXT 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [ 4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0 org.python.python 0x0000000103427889 PyImport_AddModule + 24
1 gurobipy.so 0x00000001015a4327 __Pyx_FetchCommonType + 23

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
rax: 0x0000000000000000 rbx: 0x00000001001a74c0 rcx: 0x0000000000000001 rdx: 0x0000000000000003
rdi: 0x000000010169cf11 rsi: 0x0000000000000010 rbp: 0x00007fff5fbfd230 rsp: 0x00007fff5fbfd210
r8: 0x0000000101712030 r9: 0x0000000000000000 r10: 0x0000000000001002 r11: 0xfffffffffe2b2279
r12: 0x0000000000000002 r13: 0x0000000000000000 r14: 0x000000010169cf11 r15: 0x00007fff7b364070
rip: 0x0000000103427889 rfl: 0x0000000000010206 cr2: 0x0000000000000008

Logical CPU: 0
Error Code: 0x00000004
Trap Number: 14

Binary Images:
0x100000000 - 0x100000fff +org.python.python (2.7.12 - 2.7.12) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
0x100003000 - 0x100175ff7 +org.python.python (2.7.12, [c] 2001-2016 Python Software Foundation. - 2.7.12) <831DC7C1-B842-23D7-69C8-73A7D5E5574C> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
0x1002fa000 - 0x1002fcff7 +_locale.so (???) <53986AC4-ACA1-2D91-18B0-D82D415A3A23> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
0x101100000 - 0x101102ff7 +readline.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
0x101109000 - 0x10115dfe7 +libncursesw.5.dylib (5) <3F0079C0-01C1-3CB8-19CA-F9B49AA4F4A4> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libncursesw.5.dylib
0x1011ae000 - 0x1011b1ff7 +strop.so (???) <40B05D3E-1DED-ED4E-6436-D230D8105431> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.so
0x1011b6000 - 0x1011bdff7 +itertools.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.so
0x1011c8000 - 0x1011caff7 +time.so (???) <0D2E7145-66AD-2D3C-66E4-1B9ADC5C7A59> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.so
0x1011d0000 - 0x1011d3fff +select.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.so
0x1011d9000 - 0x1011daff7 +fcntl.so (???) <8034A386-5C9A-5BFB-B43D-5CDC23C97208> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.so
0x1011dd000 - 0x1011e1ff7 +_struct.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.so
0x1011e8000 - 0x1011eafef +binascii.so (???) <1B2157C5-3275-D9B6-D20F-076434EFFC93> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.so
0x1011ee000 - 0x1011effff +cStringIO.so (???) <4F4158C8-40AC-BD52-5585-747EF47FA628> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.so
0x1011f4000 - 0x1011f8fff +_collections.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.so
0x101380000 - 0x101384fff +operator.so (???) <198AB272-F92F-F09D-86DB-4DC804FB50E3> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so
0x10138b000 - 0x10138cfff +_heapq.so (???) <71697426-5211-AEBF-F5D0-D32452547F9E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.so
0x101390000 - 0x1013a5ff7 +_io.so (???) <9FA7A71E-88D4-8909-3F82-BD0AC812C3E5> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
0x1013fd000 - 0x101402fe7 +math.so (???) <630A9AF7-CA15-F304-56AE-1BFC4D4E1B20> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/math.so
0x101409000 - 0x10140afff +_hashlib.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so
0x10140e000 - 0x10140ffff +_random.so (???) <9AD51EBD-D930-95AC-DD39-A396715FD4AC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_random.so
0x101512000 - 0x101528ff7 +_ctypes.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so
0x101579000 - 0x1016a2ff7 +gurobipy.so (0) /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gurobipy/gurobipy.so
0x103000000 - 0x10336bff7 +libgurobi65.so (0) /Library/gurobi651/*/libgurobi65.so
0x103390000 - 0x103481ff7 org.python.python (2.7.10 - 2.7.10) <83AFAAA7-BDFA-354D-8A7A-8F40A30ACB91> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
0x7fff63771000 - 0x7fff637a825f dyld (360.22) /usr/lib/dyld
0x7fff888c8000 - 0x7fff888caff7 libquarantine.dylib (80) <0F4169F0-0C84-3A25-B3AE-E47B3586D908> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
0x7fff888cb000 - 0x7fff888e7ff7 libsystem_malloc.dylib (67.40.1) <5748E8B2-F81C-34C6-8B13-456213127678> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x7fff889f0000 - 0x7fff889f0ff7 libkeymgr.dylib (28) <8371CE54-5FDD-3CE9-B3DF-E98C761B6FE0> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x7fff889f3000 - 0x7fff88d88fdb com.apple.vImage (8.0 - 8.0) <4BAC9B6F-7482-3580-8787-AB0A5B4D331B> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
0x7fff88d8f000 - 0x7fff88d96ff7 libcompiler_rt.dylib (62) /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x7fff8a36d000 - 0x7fff8a7e3fff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1258.1) <943A1383-DA6A-3DC0-ABCD-D9AEB3D0D34D> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
0x7fff8a7e4000 - 0x7fff8a7e5fff libsystem_blocks.dylib (65) <1244D9D5-F6AA-35BB-B307-86851C24B8E5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x7fff8ad10000 - 0x7fff8ae1ffe7 libvDSP.dylib (563.5) <9AB6CA3C-4F0E-35E6-9184-9DF86E7C3DAD> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
0x7fff8b6b5000 - 0x7fff8b6defff libsystem_info.dylib (477.50.4) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x7fff8c394000 - 0x7fff8c39dff3 libsystem_notify.dylib (150.40.1) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x7fff8d8a5000 - 0x7fff8dc07f3f libobjc.A.dylib (680) <7489D2D6-1EFD-3414-B18D-2AECCCC90286> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x7fff8e046000 - 0x7fff8e057ff7 libz.1.dylib (61.20.1) /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x7fff8e5f5000 - 0x7fff8e5faff7 libmacho.dylib (875.1) <318264FA-58F1-39D8-8285-1F6254EE410E> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x7fff8f2d2000 - 0x7fff8f2fbfff libc++abi.dylib (125) /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x7fff8f3c1000 - 0x7fff8f3c2ffb libremovefile.dylib (41) <552EF39E-14D7-363E-9059-4565AC2F894E> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x7fff8f99e000 - 0x7fff8f9f1ff7 libc++.1.dylib (120.1) <8FC3D139-8055-3498-9AC5-6467CB7F4D14> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x7fff8f9f2000 - 0x7fff8f9f2ff7 liblaunch.dylib (765.50.8) <834ED605-5114-3641-AA4D-ECF31B801C50> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x7fff90e03000 - 0x7fff91010fff libicucore.A.dylib (551.51.3) <5BC80F94-C90D-3175-BD96-FF1DC222EC9C> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x7fff91108000 - 0x7fff91110ffb libsystem_dnssd.dylib (625.50.5) <4D10E12B-59B5-386F-82DA-326F18028F0A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x7fff91843000 - 0x7fff91859ff7 libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1162.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x7fff92171000 - 0x7fff9256dfff libLAPACK.dylib (1162.2) <987E42B0-5108-3065-87F0-9DF7616A8A06> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
0x7fff92acc000 - 0x7fff92aceff7 libsystem_configuration.dylib (802.40.13) <3DEB7DF9-6804-37E1-BC83-0166882FF0FF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x7fff92c73000 - 0x7fff92ca0fff libdispatch.dylib (501.40.12) /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x7fff92ed1000 - 0x7fff92ed1fff com.apple.Accelerate.vecLib (3.10 - vecLib 3.10) <054DFE32-737D-3211-9A14-0FC5E1A880E3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/vecLib
0x7fff92efc000 - 0x7fff92fe2ff7 libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (59.40.2) <2486D801-C756-3488-B519-1AA6807E8948> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
0x7fff94381000 - 0x7fff9438cff7 libcommonCrypto.dylib (60075.50.1) <93732261-34B4-3914-B7A2-90A81A182DBA> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x7fff946fc000 - 0x7fff94742ff7 libauto.dylib (186) <999E610F-41FC-32A3-ADCA-5EC049B65DFB> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
0x7fff948bb000 - 0x7fff948bcffb libSystem.B.dylib (1226.10.1) /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x7fff948bd000 - 0x7fff94a24fff libBLAS.dylib (1162.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
0x7fff94a25000 - 0x7fff94a25ff7 libunc.dylib (29) /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
0x7fff94a40000 - 0x7fff94a43ffb libdyld.dylib (360.22) /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x7fff94a44000 - 0x7fff94a5bff7 libsystem_asl.dylib (323.50.1) <41F8E11F-1BD0-3F1D-BA3A-AA1577ED98A9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x7fff94f88000 - 0x7fff94f89fff libsystem_secinit.dylib (20) <32B1A8C6-DC84-3F4F-B8CE-9A52B47C3E6B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib
0x7fff9511c000 - 0x7fff95125ff7 libsystem_pthread.dylib (138.10.4) <3DD1EF4C-1D1B-3ABF-8CC6-B3B1CEEE9559> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x7fff951d8000 - 0x7fff951ddff3 libunwind.dylib (35.3) /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x7fff9522d000 - 0x7fff9525eff7 libncurses.5.4.dylib (46) /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
0x7fff9526a000 - 0x7fff9526afff com.apple.Accelerate (1.10 - Accelerate 1.10) <185EC96A-5AF0-3620-A4ED-4D3654D25B39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
0x7fff9563d000 - 0x7fff9564dfff libbsm.0.dylib (34) <7E14504C-A8B0-3574-B6EB-5D5FABC72926> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x7fff96061000 - 0x7fff96064fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib (460.50.4) <150A9D3D-F69E-32F7-8C7B-8E72CAAFF7E4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x7fff96065000 - 0x7fff9606dfef libsystem_platform.dylib (74.40.2) <29A905EF-6777-3C33-82B0-6C3A88C4BA15> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x7fff96e16000 - 0x7fff96e8bfff com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1179.50.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x7fff974bd000 - 0x7fff9754afff libsystem_c.dylib (1082.50.1) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x7fff978d9000 - 0x7fff978eaff7 libsystem_trace.dylib (201.10.3) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x7fff97be1000 - 0x7fff97be9fff libsystem_networkextension.dylib (385.40.36) <66095DC7-6539-38F2-95EE-458F15F6D014> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x7fff98396000 - 0x7fff9840dfeb libcorecrypto.dylib (335.50.1) /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x7fff9849d000 - 0x7fff98503ff7 libsystem_network.dylib (583.50.1) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x7fff98c6d000 - 0x7fff98c84ff7 libsystem_coretls.dylib (83.40.5) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x7fff98cdf000 - 0x7fff98cfdff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (3248.50.21) <78E54D59-D2B0-3F54-9A4A-0A68D671F253> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x7fff98d0d000 - 0x7fff98d0dfff libenergytrace.dylib (10.40.1) <0A491CA7-3451-3FD5-999A-58AB4362682B> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x7fff98f6c000 - 0x7fff98f74fff libcopyfile.dylib (127) /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x7fff98f75000 - 0x7fff98fa4ffb libsystem_m.dylib (3105) <08E1A4B2-6448-3DFE-A58C-ACC7335BE7E4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x7fff9934d000 - 0x7fff9934ffff libsystem_coreservices.dylib (19.2) <1B3F5AFC-FFCD-3ECB-8B9A-5538366FB20D> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x7fff995ac000 - 0x7fff995e2fff libssl.0.9.8.dylib (59.40.2) <523FEBFA-4BF7-3A69-83B7-164265BE7F4D> /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
0x7fff99716000 - 0x7fff99717fff libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <4243B6B4-21E9-355B-9C5A-95A216233B96> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
0x7fff99ec4000 - 0x7fff99ecffff libkxld.dylib (3248.50.21) <99195052-038E-3490-ACF8-76F9AC43897E> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x7fff9af94000 - 0x7fff9af95fff com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <0239494E-FEFE-39BC-9FC7-E251BA5128F1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
0x7fff9afa5000 - 0x7fff9afb6fff libSparseBLAS.dylib (1162.2) /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x7fff9c5fa000 - 0x7fff9c6aafe7 libvMisc.dylib (563.5) <6D73C20D-D1C4-3BA5-809B-4B597C15AA86> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
0x7fff9cfbc000 - 0x7fff9cfc0fff libcache.dylib (75) <9548AAE9-2AB7-3525-9ECE-A2A7C4688447> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x7fff9d7d5000 - 0x7fff9d7feff7 libxpc.dylib (765.50.8) <54D1328E-054E-3DAA-89E2-375722F9D18F> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x7fff9d80f000 - 0x7fff9d82dffb libedit.3.dylib (43) <1D3E3152-4001-3C19-B56A-7543F1BBA47C> /usr/lib/libedit.3.dylib

External Modification Summary:
Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by this process:
task_for_pid: 0
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0
Calls made by all processes on this machine:
task_for_pid: 14184
thread_create: 0
thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=127.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=127.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=50.5M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=50.5M(100%)

                            VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE SIZE COUNT (non-coalesced) 
=========== ======= ======= 
Activity Tracing 2048K 2 
Kernel Alloc Once 4K 2 
MALLOC 39.9M 19 
MALLOC guard page 16K 4 
STACK GUARD 56.0M 2 
Stack 8192K 2 
VM_ALLOCATE 264K 4 
__DATA 4348K 87 
__LINKEDIT 92.7M 27 
__TEXT 34.7M 87 
__UNICODE 552K 2 
shared memory 12K 4 
=========== ======= ======= 
TOTAL 238.3M 230

Model: MacBookPro11,1, BootROM MBP111.0138.B17, 2 processors, Intel Core i7, 3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.16f68
Graphics: Intel Iris, Intel Iris, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343147533641465238412D50422020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x112), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the tests?  From the [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP) page

> On Linux and OSX systems the tests must be run to make the default
>   solver executable.

Comment: >>pulptest
Segmentation fault: 11

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work after running the tests as recommended by Brendan Abel, according to a similar post [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pulp-or-discuss/Um1BIvlVS5M) it seems to have worked with Python 2.6 on Mac, if that is an option I would suggest trying it

Comment: I don't know whether it is a good idea to install python 2.6 when there are a lot of new versions.